# PowerMock and EasyMock method mocking issue

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, easymock, powermock

I am new to EasyMock and PowerMock and i am stuck on probably something that is very basic.

Following is my code that i would like to test

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileOp() {
private static FileOp instance = null;
public string hostIp = "";

public static FileOp() {
    if(null == instance)
        instance = new FileOp();
}

private FileOp() {
    init();
}

init() {
    hostIp = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
}

public boolean deleteFile(String fileName) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    if(file.exists()) {
        if(file.delete())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Following is my test code...

```
    import org.easymock.EasyMock;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
    import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
    import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
    import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;

    import java.io.File;

    import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(FileOp.class)
    public class FileOp_JTest
    {

@Test
@PrepareForTest(File.class)
public void deleteFile_Success(){
    try {
        final String path = "samplePath";

        //Prepare
        File fileMock = EasyMock.createMock(File.class);

        //Setup
        PowerMock.expectNew(File.class, path).andReturn(fileMock);
        expect(fileMock.exists()).andReturn(true);
        expect(fileMock.delete()).andReturn(true);

        PowerMock.replayAll(fileMock);

        //Act
        FileOp fileOp = Whitebox.invokeConstructor(FileOp.class);
        assertTrue(fileOp.deleteFile(path));

        //Verify
        PowerMock.verifyAll();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        assertFalse(true);
    }
}
```

}

The test is failing because of 
    assertTrue(fileOp.deleteFile(path));

I traced it down to deleteFile("samplePath") when invoked tries to do file.exists() and it is returning false. However, i have mocked file.exists() to return true.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. The test passed once i put both the File and FileOp classes at the class level for PrepareForTest

I also saw that if i remove @PrepareForTest from the class level and put @PrepareForTest({File.class, FileOp.class}) the tests pass.

As you can see here i have put one @PrepareForTest(File.class) at the class level and PrepareForTest(FileOp.class) at the method level.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The file you are using in your test is not mocked. You have your fileMock, but it is not used within your test. The method you are testing instantiates it's own fresh File object in the following line:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
```

If your deleteFile method would take a File object instead of a String you could inject your mockObject there and check if all calls are correct.